# WPF RichTextBox - Multiple Block Selection

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

Hi I'm currently working on a WPF project (with/ C#) that involves the use of **RichTextBox**. I currently have completed most of my work, but need assistance obtaining more than one block via mouse selection, for instance to set TextAlignment or Margin. For your reference, the following will select ***one*** block by setting a TextPointer for the **RichTextBox** caret, and then iterating through Document.Blocks to obtain an individual block. But I want an approach that will allow me to obtain more than just one block. Could somebody provide more insight on how to select ***multiple*** blocks (each block on a different line)?

```
// XAML

<RichTextBox Name="rtb" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
   <FlowDocument>
      <Paragraph TextAlignment="Left" Margin="0.0">
         <Run Text="Hello"/>
      </Paragraph>
      <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0.0">
         <Run Text="World"/>
      </Paragraph>
      <Paragraph TextAlignment="Left" Margin="1.0">
         <Run Text="Hello"/>
      </Paragraph>
      <Paragraph TextAlignment="Right" Margin="1.0">
         <Run Text="World"/>
      </Paragraph>
   </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>


// Code Behind

var curCaret = rtb.CaretPosition;
Block curBlock = rtb.Document.Blocks.Where(x => x.ContentStart.CompareTo(curCaret) ==    -1 && x.ContentEnd.CompareTo(curCaret) == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Please edit your question to clarify the following issues: (A) Do you want to select all paragraphs, or only certain paragraphs? If only certain paragraphs are desired, how would you decide which paragraphs to select? Would it be any paragraph which is already either completely or partially selected? (B) What do you mean with "to select"? Selecting of the respective document parts in the RichTextBox, or - as code example suggests - obtaining the Block objects representing the paragraphs you are interested in?

Comment: (A) I want to select certain paragraphs. The user would decide which paragraph to select by clicking and dragging over the text (i.e. text inside the RichTextBox).       
                                                                   (B) By select, I mean obtaining the Block objects representing the paragraphs. Basically, I want to do exactly what my current code does but "obtain" more than one Block object representing the paragraphs. Currently, the above code obtains only one Block object (i.e by caret position).

Comment: @elgonzo - pretty sure OP wants to implement the ability for the user to select multiple continuous ranges of text simultaneously.  E.g. in Word, a user can select a range of text with click-drag, then hold the control key down and click-drag somewhere else and add another disjoint range to the selection set.

Comment: @user3803929 - my impression is that this is not supported.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is nearly identical to the post from [WPF RichTextBox - Selected Block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553090/wpf-richtextbox-selected-block). However whereas only one block gets selected, I want to select all blocks within rtb.Selection.Text (not all text inside rtb) if that makes any sense. I'm still learning WPF RichTextBox.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to find the top-level [`Blocks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that overlap the current [selection range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.selection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can do this:

```
public static class FlowDocumentHelper
{
    public static bool Overlaps(this TextElement element, TextPointer start, TextPointer end)
    {
        return element.ContentEnd.CompareTo(start) > 0 && element.ContentStart.CompareTo(end) < 0;
    }
}
```

and then

```
var blocks = richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Where(block => block.Overlaps(richTextBox.Selection.Start, richTextBox.Selection.End));
```

However, if you are looking for the [paragraphs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.paragraph%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that overlap the current selection range this will not work because they could be buried deep inside the text element hierarchy, for instance inside a [figure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.figure%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inside a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.list%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inside a [table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.table%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inside a [section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.section%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  To actually discover the paragraphs overlapping the current selection range, you have to recursively walk the hierarchy of blocks, and WPF provides no straightforward way to do this (though they certainly have this information internally!).

Thus one could either handcraft recursive iterators for all possible [`TextElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes that might contain children, or iterate through all the [`TextPointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textpointer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects in the document and use them to discover the hierarchy.  The following uses the latter strategy:

```
public static class FlowDocumentHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<TTextElement> WalkTextRange<TTextElement>(this FlowDocument doc, TextPointer start, TextPointer end) where TTextElement : TextElement
    {
        var lastVisited = new Dictionary<int, TTextElement>();
        foreach (var stack in doc.WalkTextHierarchy())
        {
            var element = stack.Peek() as TTextElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                TTextElement previous;
                if (!lastVisited.TryGetValue(stack.Count - 1, out previous) || previous != element)
                {
                    if (element.Overlaps(start, end))
                        yield return element;
                    lastVisited[stack.Count - 1] = element;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool Overlaps(this TextElement element, TextPointer start, TextPointer end)
    {
        return element.ContentEnd.CompareTo(start) > 0 && element.ContentStart.CompareTo(end) < 0;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Stack<DependencyObject>> WalkTextHierarchy(this FlowDocument doc)
    {
        if (doc == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        var stack = new Stack<DependencyObject>();

        // Keep a TextPointer for FlowDocument.ContentEnd handy, so we know when we're done.
        TextPointer docEnd = doc.ContentEnd;

        // Keep going until the TextPointer is equal to or greater than ContentEnd.
        for (var iterator = doc.ContentStart; 
            (iterator != null) && (iterator.CompareTo(docEnd) < 0);
            iterator = iterator.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward))
        {
            var parent = iterator.Parent;

            // Identify the type of content immediately adjacent to the text pointer.
            TextPointerContext context = iterator.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward);

            switch (context)
            {
                case TextPointerContext.ElementStart:
                case TextPointerContext.EmbeddedElement:
                case TextPointerContext.Text:
                    PushElement(stack, parent);
                    yield return stack;
                    break;

                case TextPointerContext.ElementEnd:
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new System.Exception("Unhandled TextPointerContext " + context.ToString());
            }

            switch (context)
            {
                case TextPointerContext.ElementEnd:
                case TextPointerContext.EmbeddedElement:
                case TextPointerContext.Text:
                    PopToElement(stack, parent);
                    break;

                case TextPointerContext.ElementStart:
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new System.Exception("Unhandled TextPointerContext " + context.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    static int IndexOf<T>(Stack<T> source, T value)
    {
        int index = 0;
        var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            if (comparer.Equals(item, value))
                return index;
            index++;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    static void PopToElement<T>(Stack<T> stack, T item)
    {
        for (int index = IndexOf(stack, item); index >= 0; index--)
            stack.Pop();
    }

    static void PushElement<T>(Stack<T> stack, T item)
    {
        PopToElement(stack, item);
        stack.Push(item);
    }
}
```

And then

```
var paragraphs = richTextBox.Document.WalkTextRange<Paragraph>(richTextBox.Selection.Start, richTextBox.Selection.End);
```

(Note - Moderately tested non-production code.)

Finally, if you want to allow your users to Ctrl-Select multiple ranges of text that are not next to each other, as can be done in Word as described here: [Select items that aren't next to each other](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-select-items-that-are-not-next-to-each-other-8b9c1be9-cca3-935a-7cbf-94403aa48d2e), then I think you are out of luck.  RichTextBox does not appear to support this user interaction.

Comment: @user3803929 - if your question is answered, please do [mark it as such](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow).  Thanks!