# RichTextBox add Table to CaretPosition

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

How to add a `Table` (or other objects not text) to `RichTextBox` at the current `CaretPosition`.  I know how to add it to the end;

```
MyRichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(MyTable);
```

That works perfectly fine.  I know how to add text to the current

```
MyRichTextBox.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun("Some Text");
```

However, putting the `Table` at `CaretPosition` I am not sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF RichTextBox - Selected Block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553090/wpf-richtextbox-selected-block)

Comment: I marked as duplicate because I think once you have the value of the current block you can just insert the table to it.